# Removing parts of filenames

Tags: batch-file, filenames

I am needing a batch file to remove in some instances but not all double Parenthesis (including Contents) in filenames. Most of the files in my directory have only 1 set in the filenames, but some up to 5. But what I have for my code will not remove either of them if there are 2 or more sets.

Example:

```
Test Filename (xxx) (xxx).txt
```

To:

```
Test Filename.txt
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Here is my code

```
@echo off
set $path="%CD%"
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=^(^)" %%a in ('dir /b/a-d %$path%') do (
if exist %$path%\"%%a(%%b)%%c" ren %$path%\"%%a(%%b)%%c" "%%a%%c"
)
```

Comment: I would use my [JREN.BAT regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081), in which case the solution is as simple as - `call jren " *\(.*?\) *" ""`

Comment: So do you want to remove *all* parenthesised parts from the file names or the *first* or the *last* one only? To remove just the first one, replace `tokens=1-3` by `tokens=1-2*`...

Comment: I would like to remove all of them up to 5 if possible.

Comment: I managed to use JREN.BAT and it works tested up to 3 sets of parenthesis.  However I would still like to figure this out in batch also.